# C: How make a ArrayList implementation compatible with UNICODE_STRING data?

Tags: c, visual-studio, data-structures, struct

This following code must be able of add to ArrayList each process name since that current name still not is stored on list. The code of ArrayList implementation was from [this](http://m-hewedy.blogspot.com.br/2010/09/java-like-arraylist-in-c.html) reference, but have a trouble that, when changed `int` to `UNICODE_STRING` data (in `Element` structure, cause a sintaxe error on line:

```
if (e.data == list->elements[index].data) return index;
```

> Error 1   error C2088: '==' : illegal for struct

of `indexOf()` routine.

So, how fix?

**Code:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Winternl.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ntdll.lib")

typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO
{
    ULONG                   NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG                   NumberOfThreads;
    LARGE_INTEGER           Reserved[3];
    LARGE_INTEGER           CreateTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER           UserTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER           KernelTime;
    UNICODE_STRING          ImageName;
    ULONG                   BasePriority;
    HANDLE                  ProcessId;
    HANDLE                  InheritedFromProcessId;
}SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO, *PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO;

typedef struct
{
    UNICODE_STRING data;
}Element;

typedef struct
{
    int current;
    int size;
    int increment_rate;
    Element *elements;
}ArrayList;

void initWithSizeAndIncRate(ArrayList *const list, int size, int rate)
{
    list->size = size;
    list->increment_rate = rate;
    list->elements = (Element*)calloc(sizeof(Element), list->size);
    list->current = -1;
}

void initWithSize(ArrayList *const list, int size)
{
    initWithSizeAndIncRate(list, size, 50);
}

void init(ArrayList *const list)
{
    initWithSize(list, 100);
}

void arraryCopy(void *dest, int dIndex, const void* src, int sIndex, int len, int destLen, size_t size)
{
    uint8_t *udest = (uint8_t*)dest;
    uint8_t *usrc = (uint8_t*)src;
    dIndex *= size;
    sIndex *= size;
    len *= size;
    destLen *= size;

    if (src != dest)
    {
        memcpy(&udest[dIndex], &usrc[sIndex], len);
    }
    else
    {
        if (dIndex > sIndex)
        {
            uint8_t *tmp = (uint8_t*)calloc(destLen, size);
            memcpy(tmp, &udest[dIndex], (destLen - dIndex));
            memcpy(&udest[dIndex], &usrc[sIndex], len);
            memcpy(&udest[dIndex + len], tmp, (destLen - dIndex));
            free(tmp);
        }
        else if (sIndex > dIndex)
        {
            memcpy(&udest[dIndex], &usrc[sIndex], (destLen - sIndex) + 1);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
}

void clear(ArrayList *const list)
{
    while (list->current >= 0)
    {
        list->elements[list->current] = (Element){ 0 };
        list->current--;
    }
}

void wide(ArrayList* const list)
{
    list->size += list->increment_rate;
    Element *newArr = (Element*)calloc(sizeof(Element), list->size);
    arraryCopy(newArr, 0, list->elements, 0, list->current, list->size, sizeof(Element));
    free(list->elements);
    list->elements = newArr;
}

int add(ArrayList *const list, Element e)
{
    if (++list->current < list->size)
    {
        list->elements[list->current] = e;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        wide(list);
        list->elements[list->current] = e;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int indexOf(const ArrayList *const list, Element e)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index <= list->current)
    {
        if (e.data == list->elements[index].data) return index;
        index++;
    }
    return 0;
}

void printElement(const Element *const e)
{
    printf("%i ", e->data);
}

void print(const ArrayList *const list)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= list->current; i++)
    {
        Element e = list->elements[i];
        printElement(&e);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void clean(ArrayList *list)
{
    free(list->elements);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    PVOID buffer;
    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO spi;
    ArrayList list;

    init(&list);

    buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 1024 * 1024, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (!buffer)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to allocate memory for process list (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\nProcess list allocated at address %#x\n", buffer);
    spi = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO)buffer;

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, spi, 1024 * 1024, NULL)))
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to query process list (%#x)\n", status);

        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    while (spi->NextEntryOffset)
    {
        printf("\nProcess name: %wZ | Process ID: %d\n", &spi->ImageName, spi->ProcessId);

        int i = indexOf(&list, (Element){ spi->ImageName });

        if (i > 0)
            print("process already in list \n");
        else
            add(&list, (Element){ spi->ImageName });

        spi = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO)((LPBYTE)spi + spi->NextEntryOffset);
    }
    VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    print(&list);
    clean(&list);

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

After answer of @Johnny Mopp below, now how call correctly `indexof` routine?
I tried like this:

```
int i = indexOf(&list, (Element){ &spi->ImageName.Buffer });

        if (i >= 0)
            printf("process already in list \n");
        else
            add(&list, (Element){ &spi->ImageName.Buffer });
```

but `indexof` say that all already is present in list, this is wrong!

---

**EDIT 2**:

Error after first edition of answer:
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ230.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNICODE_STRING is a struct. You'll have to either do memcmp() on the entire struct or wcscmp() on e.data.Buffer

```
int indexOf(const ArrayList *const list, Element e)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index <= list->current)
    {
        // Check same lengths and then do string compare
        if (e.data.Length == list->elements[index].data.Length &&
             0 == wcsncmp(e.data.Buffer,
                          list->elements[index].data.Buffer,
                          list->elements[index].data.Length))
            return index;
        index++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

// Update after comment

Here's the whole thing with proper memory management of the `UNICODE_STRING`s

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Winternl.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"ntdll.lib")

typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO
{
    ULONG                   NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG                   NumberOfThreads;
    LARGE_INTEGER           Reserved[3];
    LARGE_INTEGER           CreateTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER           UserTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER           KernelTime;
    UNICODE_STRING          ImageName;
    ULONG                   BasePriority;
    HANDLE                  ProcessId;
    HANDLE                  InheritedFromProcessId;
}SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO, *PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO;

typedef struct
{
    // Changed to be a pointer
    UNICODE_STRING *data;
}Element;

typedef struct
{
    int current;
    int size;
    int increment_rate;
    Element *elements;
}ArrayList;

// Duplicate a UNICODE_STRING
UNICODE_STRING * CopyUString(UNICODE_STRING *src)
{
    UNICODE_STRING *dest = (UNICODE_STRING *) malloc(sizeof UNICODE_STRING);
    dest->Length = src->Length;
    dest->MaximumLength = src->MaximumLength;
    dest->Buffer = (PWSTR) malloc(sizeof WCHAR * dest->MaximumLength);
    memcpy(dest->Buffer, src->Buffer, sizeof WCHAR * dest->MaximumLength);
    return dest;
}
// Free a duplicated UNICODE_STRING
void FreeUString(UNICODE_STRING *src)
{
    free(src->Buffer);
    free(src);
}

void initWithSizeAndIncRate(ArrayList *const list, int size, int rate)
{
    list->size = size;
    list->increment_rate = rate;
    list->elements = (Element*) calloc(sizeof(Element), list->size);
    list->current = -1;
}

void initWithSize(ArrayList *const list, int size)
{
    initWithSizeAndIncRate(list, size, 50);
}

void init(ArrayList *const list)
{
    initWithSize(list, 100);
}

void arraryCopy(void *dest, int dIndex, const void* src, int sIndex, int len, int destLen, size_t size)
{
    uint8_t *udest = (uint8_t*) dest;
    uint8_t *usrc = (uint8_t*) src;
    dIndex *= size;
    sIndex *= size;
    len *= size;
    destLen *= size;

    if (src != dest)
    {
        memcpy(&udest[dIndex], &usrc[sIndex], len);
    }
    else
    {
        if (dIndex > sIndex)
        {
            uint8_t *tmp = (uint8_t*) calloc(destLen, size);
            memcpy(tmp, &udest[dIndex], (destLen - dIndex));
            memcpy(&udest[dIndex], &usrc[sIndex], len);
            memcpy(&udest[dIndex + len], tmp, (destLen - dIndex));
            free(tmp);
        }
        else if (sIndex > dIndex)
        {
            memcpy(&udest[dIndex], &usrc[sIndex], (destLen - sIndex) + 1);
        }
        else
            return;
    }
}

void clear(ArrayList *const list)
{
    while (list->current >= 0)
    {
        FreeUString(list->elements[list->current].data);
        list->current--;
    }
}

void wide(ArrayList* const list)
{
    list->size += list->increment_rate;
    Element *newArr = (Element*) calloc(sizeof(Element), list->size);
    arraryCopy(newArr, 0, list->elements, 0, list->current, list->size, sizeof(Element));
    free(list->elements);
    list->elements = newArr;
}

int add(ArrayList *const list, Element *e)
{
    if (++list->current < list->size)
    {
        list->elements[list->current].data = CopyUString(e->data);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        wide(list);
        list->elements[list->current].data = CopyUString(e->data);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int indexOf(const ArrayList *const list, Element *e)
{
    int index = 0;
    while (index <= list->current)
    {
        // Check same lengths and then do string compare
        if (e->data->Length == list->elements[index].data->Length &&
            0 == wcsncmp(e->data->Buffer,
            list->elements[index].data->Buffer,
            list->elements[index].data->Length))
            return index;
        index++;
    }
    return 0;
}

void printElement(const Element *const e)
{
    wprintf(L"%s ", e->data->Buffer);
}

void print(const ArrayList *const list)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= list->current; i++)
    {
        Element e = list->elements[i];
        printElement(&e);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void clean(ArrayList *list)
{
    free(list->elements);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv [])
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    PVOID buffer;
    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO spi;
    ArrayList list;

    init(&list);

    buffer = VirtualAlloc(NULL, 1024 * 1024, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (!buffer)
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to allocate memory for process list (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    printf("\nProcess list allocated at address %#x\n", buffer);
    spi = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO) buffer;

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, spi, 1024 * 1024, NULL)))
    {
        printf("\nError: Unable to query process list (%#x)\n", status);

        VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        return -1;
    }

    Element e;
    while (spi->NextEntryOffset)
    {
        printf("\nProcess name: %wZ | Process ID: %d\n", &spi->ImageName, spi->ProcessId);

        e.data = &(spi->ImageName);
        int i = indexOf(&list, &e);

        if (i > 0)
            printf("process already in list \n");
        else
            add(&list, &e);

        spi = (PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO) ((LPBYTE) spi + spi->NextEntryOffset);
    }
    VirtualFree(buffer, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    print(&list);
    clean(&list);

    _getch();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you. Now how call this routine after this changes? see my edition please.

Comment: this sintaxe (`Element e = { .data = spi->ImageName };`) generates an error, see my edition 2.

Comment: @LuizEduardo Ok, I fixed it. I notices another problem: you do a shallow copy of the UNICODE_STRING. You need to change that.